# Snort Modules Tweaking

Tags: kali-linux, source-code, snort, ubuntu

I want to tweak and add new functionalities to snort code(Preprocessor)(v2.9.8).

So,i have installed snort using source code,on ubuntu 14.04,however due to unknown problems,functionalities aren't working as per my requirements.

Therefore instead of installing from source code again,I want installation to be done automatically(like easyids,security-onion) and let me focus on snort code tweaking.

But i am unaware whether Security-onion,EasyIds allows making changes to snort code,as it would be possible if installation is done using snortsource code.

I have also seen that backtrack/kali-linux is preinstalled with snort,but i wish to know where is the location of snort source code to make changes.

If anybody knows better options,please suggest!

Thanks